# Const objects that refer to one another

Tags: c++

As a motivation to help visualize the problem (otherwise just skip to the code, below), suppose I'm coding a card game whereby having certain cards "in play" allows you to "buy" other cards in your hand. So, for example, suppose you have a hand of say four cards that contains an ace, and you decide to play it. Then you get another hand of four cards and now the ace allows you to play, say, a Queen card for free. Et cetera.

Now, I want to code this game. I create a `Card` struct:

```
struct Card {
  std::string name_;

  Card(const std::string name) : name_{name} {}

  std::string name() const { return name; }
};

const Card ace("ace");
const Card one("one");
// etc.
```

But then I decide I want to also record not only the name of a card, but also what card it gives for free *and* also what cards give this one for free. Say something like this:

```
struct Card {
  std::string name_;
  const Card* parent_; // card that gave this card for free
  const Card* child_;  // card that this card gives for free

  Card(const std::string name) : name_{name} {}

  std::string name() const { return name; }
  std::string parent() const { return parent_->name(); }
  std::string child() const { return child_->name(); }
};
```

(This code is obviously fragmentary and not very robust, but I just want to get the principle across.) In order to add parents/children I also create the following methods:

```
struct Card {
  // ...

  private:
    void set_parent(const Card* c) {
      parent_ = c;
    }
  public:
    void add_child(Card& c) {
      child_ = &c;
      c.set_parent(this);
    }

  // ...
};
```

Now, I can create the `Card` objects like this:

```
Card ace("ace");
Card queen("queen");
// etc.

ace.add_child(queen);
// etc.
```

But, I've had to sacrifice the constness of the `Card` objects. Let me make it clear that this is just a basic example. The code that I intend to write has in its `Card` class many data members. Thus, I would like to point to parent/children cards without explicitly duplicating the data. I also have many "cards", so I would prefer not duplicating as much data as possible.

My question is this: is there any way for me to keep the `Card` objects as const (since they will *never* contain variable data)? Or am I thinking about this wrong?

Possibly related to this question is the implicit one: is this even important? Are there good practical reasons for me to want this functionally-constant object as const in the code? Even if there aren't, then even so, is there a way to make these objects const just out of interest.

Comment: Is the mapping 1:1 or not?  You say "what cards give this one for free" - does that mean a fixed set of four cards always give one specific card?  Or does an Ace always give a Queen?  Can two different cards give the same card?  Can one card give a (random?) choice of two different cards?

Comment: In my real code I will have something like what you asked. So, translated to this example, I would have say, A -> 1; 1 -> {K or Q}, 3 -> {K or Q}, 4 -> K, 5 -> Q, 6 -> {nothing} etc. Basically, in principle, the parent and child lists may be empty, or any number; and independent of one another. They are hard-coded from the start though, and do not change once set. In the question I kept it simple by being 1:1 because I imagine once the basic principle has a solution I can make it more complex myself.

Answer (score 1):

As you have pointed out, a Card's data (its identity plus some rules about it) are constant.  Moreover, they are known at compile time.  So:

```
#include <array>

enum class Rank {
    None, Ace, Two, Three, Four // ...
};

struct Card
{
    Rank rank = Rank::None;
    std::array<Rank, 2> from = {};
    std::array<Rank, 2> to = {};
};

constexpr Card cards[] = {
    {},
    {Rank::Ace, {Rank::Two, Rank::Three}, {}},
    {Rank::Two, {}, {Rank::Ace}},
    {Rank::Three, {Rank::Four}, {Rank::Ace, Rank::Four}},
    {Rank::Four, {Rank::Three}},
};
```

You can make the arrays as large as you need.  Now you have a full set of data which is all known at compile time, and which is compact in storage.

Comment: Ah, sorry, in retrospect I didn't make this clear. The data associated to the Card will not just be the ranks of its parents and children (that was just to keep things simple and readable). There will be more class members than just the ones in my example. Hence why I want to point to the Card object itself and not just duplicate the parent/child card data. Sorry again! I'll make this clear in the question. Otherwise, this would, of course, work. But, it would be prohibitive for many class data members and many cards.

Comment: @Zorawar: I've edited my answer now to store all the cards in an array.  Now you can attach more data to each card whilst being able to jump between them, e.g. `cards[unsigned(mycard.from[0])]` to get the first "from" card for `mycard`.  You can think of the `from` and `to` arrays as "relative" pointers now, which should be just as good as actual pointers since the overall `cards` array is global.

Comment: Ah I see. So you suggest, essentially, that I assign some unique identifier to each card and use that as a "pointer" instead. (In the example above, the rank is that natural choice.) For more complicated objects, however, I assign something else unique. And, moreover, an enum class would be better than a string name. Not a bad idea. I wonder if there's a way to do this with actual pointers though, just out of interest.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot construct `const` objects referring to each other without breaking the rules of constructing them properly.  But....

You can statically construct them read-write, as `private`, `static` class members, and then publish `const` references to them.  This will make the access to those members read-only.

## sample.h

```
class Sample {
    const int priv_ro;  /* this is true const field */
    int       priv_rw;  /* this is read-write */
public:
    const int& pub_ro_ro; /* read only alias */
    const int& pub_rw_ro; /* idem */
    //int& pub_ro_rw; /* error, cannot alias a const as read write */
    int& pub_rw_rw; /* correct, public read write alias to private field */
    static Sample global_rw; /* static global variable (read-write) */
    static const Sample global_ro; /* static global variable (read-only) */
private:
    Sample(int ro, int rw):
        priv_ro(ro),
        priv_rw(rw),
        pub_ro_ro(this->priv_ro),
        pub_rw_ro(this->priv_rw),
        pub_rw_rw(this->priv_rw)
    {
        //priv_ro = ro; /* error, priv_ro is const */
        priv_rw = rw; /* ok */
    }
};
```

## sample.cc

```
#include "sample.h"

Sample Sample::global_rw(8,3);
const Sample Sample::global_ro(5,2);
```

## main.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include "sample.h"

#define P(x) do{ std::cout << #x " = " << x << std::endl; } while(0)

int main()
{
    P(Sample::global_rw.pub_ro_ro);
    P(Sample::global_rw.pub_rw_ro);
    P(Sample::global_rw.pub_rw_rw);
    P(Sample::global_ro.pub_ro_ro);
    P(Sample::global_ro.pub_rw_ro);
    P(Sample::global_ro.pub_rw_rw);
    // Sample::global_ro.pub_ro_ro = 0; /* cannot assign. */
    // Sample::global_ro.pub_rw_ro = 0; /* cannot assign. */
    // Sample::global_ro.pub_rw_rw = 0; /* cannot assign. */
    // Sample::global_rw.pub_ro_ro = 0; /* cannot assign. */
    // Sample::global_rw.pub_rw_ro = 0; /* cannot assign. */
    Sample::global_rw.pub_rw_rw = 0;
    P(Sample::global_rw.pub_ro_ro);
    P(Sample::global_rw.pub_rw_ro);
    P(Sample::global_rw.pub_rw_rw);
    P(Sample::global_ro.pub_ro_ro);
    P(Sample::global_ro.pub_rw_ro);
    P(Sample::global_ro.pub_rw_rw);
}
```

## Makefile

```
targets=sample

sample_objs=sample.o main.o
sample: $(sample_objs)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(sample_objs)
```

If you uncomment the commented lines, you'll see the non-accessible field or `const` definition error.